# Cannot install the DPpackage in R

Tags: r

I try to install the DPpackage in R, but is not available for R version 4.0.2. However, I made a search and I found out that it was removed from Cran. Is there any other way to install it ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the following

```
packageurl <- "https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/DPpackage/DPpackage_1.1-7.tar.gz"
install.packages(packageurl, repos=NULL, type="source")
```

I have used the last released package from CRAN: https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/DPpackage/
If you want another version, please change the corresponding URL

Comment: Really helpful!! Thank you!